# What does やって mean in やって来ない？

Tags: grammar

As far as I can tell, both of these sentences:

> 風はやって来ない。
>
> 風は来ない。

mean:

> The wind does not come.

What does the やって (which I assume is やる in て-form) add to the meaning of the first phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The やって part is 遣って when written in 漢字.

遣る can be seen in words like 派遣{はけん} or 目を遣る.
遣る in these words means to direct/send something in a certain direction.

Now I believe you already now what 来る means. When you add やって in front of it, it adds the "direction" meaning I stated above to 来る. You can also see this in the [definition of やってくる](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%81%A3%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B-648649):

> １ こちらに向かってくる。「向こうから―・くる」

So when you add やって in your sentence, the wind is coming from some other place *directed/approaching* towards the speaker. This also shows there is some relative distance between the speaker and the thing coming which cannot be seen with just 来る (as 来る just means to come).

Also, it is not stated in the definition, but I think the やって adds some significance/importance to the thing that is coming. For example, you can say 台風がやってきた or 春がやってきた as both of these things have significance. So in your examples, the 風 has more importance when やって is used (perhaps it is wanted/needed for some reason).

I think the above comes from the definition of [遣る](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%81%A3%E3%82%8B-649916) as it can mean:

> １ そこへ行かせる。さしむける。送り届ける

In other words, it is a deliberate action. Going deeper you can think of the wind in your example as happening by "fate" rather than just a natural phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation in Japanese of「やって来る」 in weblio

http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B

It means not just "come" but "come from a long distance."

So, the expression of "風はやって来ない。" is unnatural for Japanese natives. However it could be a description for a situation. It depends on the context where it is used.

When you lost the way and there is no rescue and you are ding, you can say

"とうとう救援はやって来なかった"