# Meaning of やって in 方法をやって見せ

Tags: grammar

> 次にマダム・フーチは箒の端から滑り落ちないように箒にまたがる方法を**やって**見せ、...
> Next Madam Hooch showed them how to straddle the broom so they didn't slide off the end, ...

I don't understand what やって is doing in this sentence.

Not sure if [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42082/what-does-%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-mean-in-%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) is related, but I can't really make a link with this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This やる is simply "to do" or "to carry out". This やる indicates that she taught how to straddle the broom not by explaining it verbally but by actually doing it. ("To do a method" may not be a common collocation in English, but 方法をやる is acceptable in Japanese.)

(やってくる is a fixed compound verb, and you should not apply this やって to other verbs.)